# Time2Vec layer in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

How to implement Time2Vec with Transformers in Pytorch?

I have seen this https://github.com/ojus1/Time2Vec-PyTorch but I am not sure how to implement it when we have an input of shape (batch_size, seq_len, features).

Any Pytorch implementation of something similar to this Keras implementation https://gist.github.com/Anuj040/9402d433e0c7f1625f0af737ff03a02d.